# How to detect which file error in Lavel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learing laravel 5. A day, when I run `php artisan` command I got this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\premiumlens\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\premiumlens\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 102
```

Almost application functions work perfect. But may not all. I'm sure the error is not caused by `UrlGenerator.php`

Now I cant use any `artisan` functions. How can I detect which file cause this issue.

Thank you !

Comment: I use phpunit and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `url()` helper in your config file, find where you put `url()` helper in your config file and remove it. your problem will be solved. i had this same problem and solved by removing `url()` form config file..

```
url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/highcharts.css'),
```